# Why printf show false value of an hex number

Tags: c, hex, printf

**Code**

```
char a; 
a = 0xf1;
printf("%x\n", a);
```

**Output**

```
fffffff1
```

`printf()` show 4 bytes, that exactly we have one byte in `a`.

What is the reason of this misbehavior?

How can i correct it?

Comment: wrong format. Try `int a`

Comment: `char a;` --> `unsigned char a;`

Comment: It casted to an integer, which extended the sign

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  `printf("%zu", sizeof(int));` show 4 byte, i want only one byte.

Comment: A `char` would be promoted to `int` by virtue of the integer promotions anyway....

Comment: @DavidBowling its true David. but consider `int` have 4 byte length, and `char` have only one byte, try `sizeof`. i know any characters in C cast to appropriate ASCII.

Comment: @EsmaeelE You can try `sizeof`, but by the time you finish writing a `printf`-like function in order to test the `sizeof` its argument, you could have just read the manual... In fact, you *should* read the manual.

Comment: @EsmaeelE There is no requirement in standard C that ASCII be the character set used. Consider that C also runs on machines using EBCDIC.

Comment: @EsmaeelE The comments section is for requesting and providing clarification for the question you asked. Please don't diverge so much from the original topic. I'm not your research hound. You can find that information.

Comment: @EsmaeelE-- if you just google [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) you would get the Wikipedia page I just linked to.

Comment: @Seb about first your comment,  I must read which manual instead of use `sizeof`?

Comment: @EsmaeelE I assume you're programming for a Unix system, since you're using a Unix programming language, so a Unix manual might be a good place to start! [Here's one](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdarg.h.html)... Pay careful attention to the parts about *integer promotion*!

Comment: @EsmaeelE [Here's one about a common compiler/standard library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Calling-Variadics.html) which says "objects of type char or short int (whether signed or not) are promoted to either int or unsigned int" and "if the caller passes a char as an optional argument, it is promoted to an int, and the function can access it with va_arg (ap, int)."

Comment: @EsmaeelE You can't safely learn C by trial and error! It has undefined behaviours which you must learn to avoid unless you want to risk being sued for losses caused by serious bugs (e.g. the heartbleed SSL bug). Fortunately the technology you're using comes with manuals which you can read... so read them *BEFORE* you resort to guessing! Perhaps your guessing might lead you to some flawed conclusion which works for your system, then gets you in trouble because it doesn't for some other... at least the manual would be your defense in court.

Comment: @Seb how to seperate, bytes with `printf()` ff_ff_ff_ff

Comment: @EsmaeelE The comments section here is not the right place to ask a new question. Nonetheless, *before* you ask that new question you should conduct adequate research or else you'll end up with a *closed, unanswered* question... Which research have you conducted? I recall learning about division in primary school; perhaps you should do some research into that (and its related friend, modulo)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **What is the reason of this misbehavior?**

This question looks [strangely similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665673/bit-extension-occuring-when-trying-to-store-a-byte-of-information-into-a-x/45665730#45665730) to another I have answered; it even contains a similar value (`0xfffffff1`). In that answer, I provide some information required to understand what conversion happens when you pass a small value (such as a `char`) to a variadic function such as `printf`. There's no point repeating that information here.

If you inspect `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` from `<limits.h>`, you're likely to find that your `char` type is signed, and so `0xf1` does not fit as an integer value inside of a `char`.

Instead, it ends up being converted in an implementation-defined manner, which for the majority of us means it's likely to end up with one of the high-order bits becoming the sign bit. When these values are promoted to `int` (in order to pass to `printf`), sign extension occurs to preserve the value (that is, a `char` that has a value of -1 should be converted to an int that has a value of -1 as an `int`, so too is the underlying representation for your example likely to be transformed from `0xf1` to `0xfffffff1`).

```
printf("CHAR_MIN .. CHAR_MAX: %d .. %d\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
printf("Does %d fit? %s\n", '\xFF', '\xFF' >= CHAR_MIN && '\xFF' <= CHAR_MAX ? "Yes!"
                                                                             : "No!");

printf("%d %X\n", (char) -1, (char) -1); // Both of these get converted to int
printf("%d %X\n", -1, -1);               // ... and so are equivalent to these
```

> **How can i correct it?**

Declare `a` with a type that can fit the value `0xf1`, for example `int` or `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 4):

`printf` is a variable argument function, so the compiler does its best but cannot check strict compliance between format specifier and argument type.

Here you're passing a `char` with a `%x` (integer, hex) format specifier.

So the value is promoted to a signed integer (because > 127: negative char and `char` is signed on most systems, on yours that's for sure)

Either:

- change `a` to `int` (simplest)
- change `a` to `unsigned char` (as suggested by BLUEPIXY) that takes care of the sign in the promotion
- change format to `%hhx` as stated in the various docs (note that on my gcc 6.2.1 compiler `hhx` is not recognized, even if `hx` is)

note that the compiler warns you *before* reaching `printf` that you have a problem:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:6:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 a = 0xf1;
```

Comment: some compilers do this check anyway. gcc will produce the warning, and cast char to int in this case

Comment: @PeterJ not on my version (which is a branch of 6.2.1), but thanks, I have used max warning options and got a warning _before_. gcc probably casts char to int silently, but I don't see any warning (I get warning for wrong number of parameters)

Comment: @EsmaeelE add `-Wextra` too and `-Woverflow`...

Comment: which gcc version do you have? gcc has improved since 2.95. time to upgrade. The price is cheap :)

Comment: yes: `-Woverflow` is the one.

Comment: my advice: keep it like `-Wall -Wextra` (sometimes `-Wpedantic` is a little too much)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for advice. `gcc -Wall -Wextra` not generate any message in this case. only `-Wpedantic` show that thing. and `-Woverflow` not catch.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `int a` instead of `char a` because `char` is unsigned and can store only 1 byte from 0 to 255. 
And hex number need many storage to store it, and also `int` storage size is 2 or 4 bytes. So it's good to use `int` here to store hex number.

Comment: Plain `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned`; this is implementation-dependent.

Comment: It's promoted when code is being compiled?

Comment: `0xf1` requires only one byte, so `unsigned char` would be sufficient.

Comment: on the OP's platform char specifically is *signed*; that's why they see this behaviour.

Comment: how to find out in my machine `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`?

Comment: @EsmaeelE-- check for wrap-around of negative numbers: `char x = -1;  printf("%s\n", x < 0 ? "signed char" : "unsigned char");`.